# How to use image in HTML which we add into Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

[image]

I am using Azure Functions to generate the pdf, i am generating the pdf but i am not able to get the image on pdf?
Can anyone tell me how to add image inside pdf which i have added in the folder where index.js is placed.

```
if (Code === '1416') {
  account.img = `\EmpPDF\\16.png`;
} else if (Code === '1411') {
  account.img = `\EmpPDF\\11.png`;
} else {
  account.img = `\EmpPDF\\1.png`;
}

const imgPath = Path.join(__dirname, account.img);
context.log("img Path : ", account.img);
```

Comment: It's not clear for me what you mean with `azure function`. Could you share the code of the function to make it reproducible?

Comment: i have added above the image, i have to access these images on the html which i am getting as pdf but image is not found

Answer (score 1):

I would better put images into blob storage then in azure function request them

```
  [Blob("path/to/image", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "Connection")] Stream image
```

PS> In c# you can add attribute to read files from blob storage. Not sure how to do in node [but look here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-resize-function-node)

Answer (score 0):

Put all your images in /Images folder and You can read with Context object

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log,ExecutionContext context){
log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

 string templateFile = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "Images", "azure.Jpeg");
```